# Finding subgradients

Tags: linear-programming, convex-optimization, subgradient

How would I find the subgradients of this :

$$ f(x) = \max_{i=1,\ldots,n} a_i^Tx + b_i$$

I'm new to subgradients and any hint on how to start this would be useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I(x) = \{ i \mid a_i^T x + b_i = f(x) \}$.  So $I(x)$ is the set of "active" indices.

Then
\begin{equation*}
\partial f(x) = \textbf{conv} \, \{ a_i \mid i \in I(x) \}.
\end{equation*}

This is discussed in chapter 4 ("subgradients") of Vandenberghe's [236c notes](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236c.html).  See slide 4-16.